# What's a task-manager lighter than Activity-Monitor?

Tags: software-recommendation, battery, performance, activity-monitor

Apple Activity Monitor is nice and simple enough, but I tend to keep it open all the time in order:

- to have a CPU monitor always visible in the Dock without any click/gesture (and without wasting space on the Menu Bar)
- to have quick access to details (PID, CPU/Memory/Network usage) and to killing apps

It **is good enough** but I was wondering:

does any other software exist, providing more or less the same functionalities, but with less use of CPU and (mainly) **less energy impact**?

Open-source is highly preferred.
Freeware is a nice to have.
If priced: not unreasonably

Comment: Activity Monitor's Energy Impact and CPU Usage is around 1 to 2% on both my Macs. If you're seeing significantly more than that, then it may be a local problem. How often do you need to kill apps?

Comment: Not often (or the kill themselves ). And yes, I see that normally it stays around 3-6%, but it also goes up to 30%. Not sure why though; maybe that happens when the app is displayed and am using it and the UI needs to refresh?

Comment: Any app is going to use a burst of CPU to bring itself to the front, or to move a window round the screen, or scroll through a list. But that burst will be very shortlived. If I run `top` in Terminal, that uses around 5-10%. I don't think AM is inefficient.